# Element should contain one out of three element

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a keyword with 3 arguments (3 dates) that should find en element and check if it contains one of the 3 dates.

I have no idea how to proceed.
I tried this but it obviously doesn't work:

```
Element should contain    xpath=//input[@name="date${prefixe}2"]/parent::*    ${date1}    or    ${date2}    or    ${date3}
```

And I tried this, but it also doesn't work:

```
${check1}=    Run Keyword and Return Status    Element should contain    xpath=//input[@name="date${prefixe}1"]/parent::*    ${date1}
Run Keyword If    not ${check1}    ${check1}=    Run Keyword and Return Status    Element should contain    xpath=//input[@name="date${prefixe}1"]/parent::*    ${date2}
Run Keyword If    not ${check1}    Element should contain    xpath=//input[@name="date${prefixe}1"]/parent::*    ${date3}
```

I have a "fail" at the first line as the element does not contains date1

How can I do this?

EDIT: My XPATH works fine, I get the value of my element, my problem lies in "How can I compare it to the three possibles dates I have". I don't get how I can compare my variable to 3 different strings to check which one is right.

Comment: Can you share the HMTL code of your element please?

Comment: Why the HTML? My xpath here works (if you're wondering about the date${prefixe}2 becoming date${prefixe}1, it's normal, I have 10 dates like this that I need to check) , the problem is on the robotframework syntax :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get the element value (or attribute) and then do the verification. See if [Get Element Attribute](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) or [Get Web Element](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20WebElement) can be used for that purpose.

[EDIT]
You create a list with the 3 options and then test if value is `in`.

```
@{options}=    Create List    ${date1}    ${date2}    ${date3}
Should be True    ${value} in ${options}
```

Comment: Thank you but I do get the value, my problem is on the "then do the verification". Semms like the usual "or" syntax doesn't work so I don't know how to compare i to the 3 possibles values

Comment: Yes! That is what I needed! Thank you